# Expo Go app download stuck for IOS simulator

Tags: ios, download, expo, expo-go

I have upgraded expo sdk to recent version 47.0.0.

And expo asked me to upgrade Expo Go version in IOS simulator, so I removed app in IOS simulator.

Then run `expo start --ios`
It stuck in downloading Expo Go app into IOS simulator.

To fix this, I tried these.

- tried on different IOS simulators (iPhone 12, iPhone 12 Pro)
- reset IOS simulator (Erase All Content and Settings...)
- restart Computer.
- installing fresh new app (it stucks too)

Lastly, I tried this
`expo client:install:ios`
It stuck too, but a few mins later, it shows this message.

`This download is taking longer than expected. You can also try downloading the clients from the website at https://expo.dev/tools`

[image]

Expo Info here:

[image]
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This was netowork issue, Please check VPN or Firewall or Proxy